# Redirect a subdomain to a directory with vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I'd like to redirect a subdomain to a user directory.

So I've tried this config, but it seems redirect to the root folder.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName epnet.fr
    ServerAlias *.epnet.fr

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.epnet\.fr
    RewriteCond /home/%1/apps/ -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
    <Directory /home>
        Options Includes FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For example, I've a user 'tiste', I'd like to redirect tiste.epnet.fr to /home/tiste/apps/ and then, any pages of the website which are on apps/ will be accessible tiste.epnet.fr/index.php

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Apache comes with a very convenient module for this called [`mod_userdir`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html) which would make this much easier than using just rewrites. (There's a good tutorial for it [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html).) Specifically to combine this with virtual hosts, this is documented [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-mass-virtualhosting-with-apache2-mod_rewrite-mod_userdir-mod_suexec-on-centos-5.3).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DocumentRoot

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName epnet.fr
    ServerAlias *.epnet.fr

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.epnet\.fr
    RewriteCond /home/%1/apps/ -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
    DocumentRoot /var/www/whatfolderyouwant
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure the folder you are creating has the correct permissions:

```
 sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/whatfolderyouwant
```

And then finally make sure you activate the host using the command:

```
 sudo a2ensite epnet.fr
```

This tutorial was very helpful to me when learning to setup virtual hosts on apache2:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: I agree with you, but I can't set a documentroot cause it depends on the subdomain name... Here is the issue I'm stuck in.